# Submit div content as textarea with hidden fields

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Got a form and I need to submit the content of five divs. I read many solutions and I figured I could use hidden fields, but I don't know how. Javascript or jquery would be great

```
<form name="module" id="module" method="post" action=""  title="postthis">

<div name="mytext"  id="mytext">Here's something I want to pass</div>
<div name="mytext2"  id="mytext2">Again, I want this div to act as a text area</div>
<div name="mytext3"  id="mytext3">Another text</div>
<div name="mytext4"  id="mytext4">Yet another</div>
<div name="mytext5"  id="mytext5">Last one</div>

<input name="mytext" type="hidden" id="mytext" value="mytext" />
<input name="mytext2" type="hidden" id="mytext2" value="mytext3" />
<input name="mytext3" type="hidden" id="mytext3" value="mytext4" />
<input name="mytext4" type="hidden" id="mytext4" value="mytext5" />
<input name="mytext5" type="hidden" id="mytext5" value="mytext6" />

<input name="insert" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="insert" value="Save my fields" onClick="return validate_login(module);" />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to submit `<div name="mytext" ... </div>` through a form? Also, note that element IDs must be unique

Comment: yes, I want to submit the text that's inside the five divs, so "Here's something I want to pass"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below code snippet. to help you achieve your goals. This solution is broken into two parts, the HTML markup and the Javascript code. `data-input` is used to connect corresponding hidden fields `ids`. These is then submitted to the server for processing.

```js
function augmentValues(divClass = "mytext") {
  const divs = document.getElementsByClassName(divClass);
  Array.from(divs).forEach(divElem => {
    const inputId = divElem.getAttribute("data-input");
    const hiddenInput = document.getElementById(`${inputId}`)
    hiddenInput.value = divElem.textContent
  })
  
}


function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  augmentValues();
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const formValues = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
  // Validate inputs
  // Submit form
  console.log(formValues)
  event.target.submit()
}
```

```html
<form name="module" id="module" method="post" action="" title="postthis" onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">

  <div class="mytext" data-input="mytext">Here's something I want to pass</div>
  <div class="mytext" data-input="mytext2">Again, I want this div to act as a text area</div>

  <input name="mytext" type="hidden" id="mytext" value="" />
  <input name="mytext2" type="hidden" id="mytext2" value="" />

  <button name="insert" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
Save my fields
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, strangely enough as soon as the form is submitted the values are not received by the Request.Form. Note that I have no problem giving different ids to divs and hidden fields, if that helps.

Comment: Try the latest code snippet. The form will post back now.

Comment: While this answer is good, if you could explain in a bit more detail what the code is doing and how it answers the OPs question that would improve the quality of the answer.